# BTsync's Sync Fails after Upgrades to 2.3.6 between Ubuntu and OS X

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, bittorrent-sync

I upgraded my BTsync 2.3.3 to 2.3.6 (378) in OS X 10.11.4 and Ubuntu 14.04 successfully. 
Both devices see each other, so tracking and indexing is going on. 
The main device is OS X, where the indexing is done. 
However, there is no data transfer between the two devices. 
The Ubuntu was 5 days offline so has had old files. 
I updated Ubuntu by downloading the .tar -ball, unzipping it to my Desktop and running it (moved visible folders away before) by `./BTsync` successfully. 
However, BTsync's frontend does not recognise that there is something wrong with the sync, but I see that no files are updated in the Ubuntu 14.04. 
I restarted Ubuntu three times, started separately BTsync for the verification and exclusion of errors in the setting.

A ticket was sent about the issue to the developers just a moment ago.

---

How can you start syncing again from your OS X's BTsync to BTsync in Ubuntu?